# Failed Gradle because of firebase-analytics

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, dart

I followed the instructions for adding an Android app to Firebase project but when i run the code it gives me the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

How can I solve? I just copy and paste from the offcial Firebase documentation and I'm using Flutter.

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    ...
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
dependencies{
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a version number specified for the dependency.  You can find the latest version in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
```

But since you tagged this question with Flutter, if you are building a Flutter app, you should probably instead follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics).

> To use this plugin, add firebase_analytics as a [dependency in your pubspec.yaml](https://flutter.io/platform-plugins/) file. You must also configure firebase analytics for each platform project: Android and iOS (see the example folder or https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#6 for step by step details).

You can read further in the [Firebase documentation for Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#add-flutterfire-plugins):

```
dependencies:
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
```